# no me inserta en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs

No me inserta datos a nivel de codigo, por comando si me deja

> db.nombreDB.save()

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("bot");
    var myobj = {
        "idUser": 2,
        "first_name": "Martin",
        "last_name": "Perez",
        "username": "mankito",
        "text": "texto de convesacion",
        "data": "data"

    };
    dbo.collection("conversacion").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Me salta por consola que ha sido insertado, pero luego cuando hago la consulta a través del comando mongo no me aparece

Comment: Tu código se ve bien, ¿cómo consultas los datos? Desde NodeJS, luego de hacer la inserción, ¿puedes consultar la colección para ver los datos?. Tal como tienes actualmente tu código funciona sin problemas. Hace falta más información para determinar el error. Saludos